# rcedit.exe failed with exit code 193. wine: Bad EXE format

Tags: docker, docker-compose, electron, wine

I got following error message, If I try to build my electron application in my docker container.

`build-electron_1  | rcedit.exe failed with exit code 193. wine: Bad EXE format for Z:\app\node_modules\rcedit\bin\rcedit.exe.`

```
FROM node:10-stretch

RUN apt update
RUN apt install wine freetype
```

```
version: '3.1'

services:
 build-electron:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
    working_dir: /app
    command: "make install rebuild-node-sass build-package"
```

`make install` only triggers `yarn (install)` and `make rebuild-node-sass` will start `npm rebuild node-sass`

```
"package-linux": "electron-packager ./build projectName --platform=linux --arch=x64 --overwrite --packageManager=yarn --prune=true --out=out/linux --asar --icon=build/favicon.ico",
"package-windows": "electron-packager ./build projectName --platform=win32 --arch=all --overwrite --packageManager=yarn --prune=true --out=out/windows --asar --icon=icon/icon.png.ico",
```

Comment: I already tried to install wine with `apt-add-repository https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/debian/` and `apt-get install --install-recommends winehq-stable`

Comment: Solution was to use `node:10` instead `node:10-stretch`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution is now this:

```
FROM node:10

RUN dpkg --add-architecture i386 && apt-get update && apt-get install wine wine32 -y

RUN npm install electron-packager -g

VOLUME /electron
WORKDIR /electron
```